# Build args not passing from docker-compoes.yml to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        file_url: 'some-url'
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.4-bullseye

ARG file_url

RUN curl $file_url -L -o "file"
```

When I run:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

I expect Docker'd build and start my containers. But instead, I got:

```
Step 4/12 : RUN curl $file_url -L -o "file"
 ---> Running in 59696c6274c7
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

So obviously the build args are not passing to Dockerfile. I've read a lot of similar threads on Stackoverflow but couldn't figure out what went wrong.

One more thing. I can actually build the containers with `docker-compose build web` just fine. It's just when I run `docker-compose up --build` or `docker-compose up` the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is not passed correctly in your dockerfile.
see this for variable calls inside dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Ideally it's contained inside `${variable_name}` .
this line `RUN curl $file_url -L -o "file` needs rectification.

In your Dockerfile change `$file_url` to `${file_url}`

Comment: I don't think it's the cause. The Docker doc says: `Environment variables are notated in the Dockerfile either with $variable_name or ${variable_name}. They are treated equivalently and the brace syntax is typically used to address issues with variable names with no whitespace, like ${foo}_bar.` And yes, I tried.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is not on passing the argument in the Dockerfile. The arguments are being passed correctly even if the output is `Step 4/12 : RUN curl $file_url -L -o "file"` on build. I tested it out. The problem is in your curl syntax when passing the `file_url` argument. You can test it by passing `https://stackoverflow.com/` as your `file_url` argument for example and there will be no errors. What are you trying to pass as 'some-url'? @DingYu

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. `file_url` is just a place holder. The real URL I use is `https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb` but the error was the same. Besides, I can actually build the containers with `docker-compose build web` just fine. It's just when I run `docker-compose up --build` or `docker-compose up` the error occurred.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your error and i cant! Maybe there is something cached. You can try `docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up --force-recreate` in order to  be sure that is nothing cached. (Also try removing ` ` from the 'some-url', because i had an error using them)